# using DELETE method in rest webservice, _method hidden field workaround for jersey maven project

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, maven

I am trying to create a jsp page as a client for a rest service, which i know is fully working as I have tested with JUnit.

I know html or the browsers will not support a PUT/DELETE method the way they do a GET/POST, but i have read of a work around like this one https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2011/06/04/spring3-mvc-rest/ which for some reason will not work for me. I have exhausted a lot of options and read a lot on here but can not get this to work for me at all.

Here is some of the relevant code

first of all this in my web.xml, when i place this in code in the web.xml i get a 404 error with description The requested resource is not available.

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Here is the section of the pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I had also tried

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the console log

```
Mar 20, 2017 3:22:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\Mick\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;.
Mar 20, 2017 3:22:39 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:rest' did not find a matching property.
Mar 20, 2017 3:22:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 20, 2017 3:22:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 20, 2017 3:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 531 ms
Mar 20, 2017 3:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabase open
WARNING: Exception configuring digester to permit java encoding names in XML files. Only IANA encoding names will be supported.
org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Feature: http://apache.org/xml/features/allow-java-encodings
    at org.apache.crimson.parser.XMLReaderImpl.setFeature(XMLReaderImpl.java:204)
    at org.apache.crimson.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.setFeatures(SAXParserImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.crimson.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParser0(SAXParserFactoryImpl.java:101)
    at org.apache.crimson.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.setFeature(SAXParserFactoryImpl.java:140)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.setFeature(Digester.java:538)
    at org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabase.open(MemoryUserDatabase.java:411)
    at org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory.getObjectInstance(MemoryUserDatabaseFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:143)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.nextElementInternal(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:119)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:73)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)

Mar 20, 2017 3:22:40 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester getParser
SEVERE: Digester.getParser: 
javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: Feature: http://apache.org/xml/features/allow-java-encodings
    at org.apache.crimson.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParser(SAXParserFactoryImpl.java:119)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.getParser(Digester.java:677)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.getXMLReader(Digester.java:887)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1556)
    at org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabase.open(MemoryUserDatabase.java:431)
    at org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory.getObjectInstance(MemoryUserDatabaseFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:143)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.nextElementInternal(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:119)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:73)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)

Mar 20, 2017 3:22:40 PM org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.getXMLReader(Digester.java:887)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1556)
    at org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabase.open(MemoryUserDatabase.java:431)
    at org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory.getObjectInstance(MemoryUserDatabaseFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:143)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.nextElementInternal(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:119)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:73)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)

Mar 20, 2017 3:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener createMBeans
SEVERE: Exception processing Global JNDI Resources
javax.naming.NamingException
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:860)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.nextElementInternal(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:119)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:73)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)

Mar 20, 2017 3:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 20, 2017 3:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Mar 20, 2017 3:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabase open
WARNING: Exception configuring digester to permit java encoding names in XML files. Only IANA encoding names will be supported.
org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Feature: http://apache.org/xml/features/allow-java-encodings
    at org.apache.crimson.parser.XMLReaderImpl.setFeature(XMLReaderImpl.java:204)
    at org.apache.crimson.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.setFeatures(SAXParserImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.crimson.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParser0(SAXParserFactoryImpl.java:101)
    at org.apache.crimson.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.setFeature(SAXParserFactoryImpl.java:140)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.setFeature(Digester.java:538)
    at org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabase.open(MemoryUserDatabase.java:411)
    at org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory.getObjectInstance(MemoryUserDatabaseFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:143)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm.startInternal(UserDatabaseRealm.java:255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.startInternal(CombinedRealm.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.startInternal(LockOutRealm.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)

Mar 20, 2017 3:22:40 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester getParser
SEVERE: Digester.getParser: 
javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: Feature: http://apache.org/xml/features/allow-java-encodings
    at org.apache.crimson.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParser(SAXParserFactoryImpl.java:119)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.getParser(Digester.java:677)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.getXMLReader(Digester.java:887)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1556)
    at org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabase.open(MemoryUserDatabase.java:431)
    at org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory.getObjectInstance(MemoryUserDatabaseFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:143)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm.startInternal(UserDatabaseRealm.java:255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.startInternal(CombinedRealm.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.startInternal(LockOutRealm.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)

Mar 20, 2017 3:22:40 PM org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.getXMLReader(Digester.java:887)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1556)
    at org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabase.open(MemoryUserDatabase.java:431)
    at org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory.getObjectInstance(MemoryUserDatabaseFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:143)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm.startInternal(UserDatabaseRealm.java:255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.startInternal(CombinedRealm.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.startInternal(LockOutRealm.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)

Mar 20, 2017 3:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm startInternal
SEVERE: Exception looking up UserDatabase under key UserDatabase
javax.naming.NamingException
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:860)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm.startInternal(UserDatabaseRealm.java:255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.startInternal(CombinedRealm.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.startInternal(LockOutRealm.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)

Mar 20, 2017 3:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm startInternal
SEVERE: Failed to start "org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm/1.0" realm
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Realm[UserDatabaseRealm]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.startInternal(CombinedRealm.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.startInternal(LockOutRealm.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: No UserDatabase component found under key UserDatabase
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm.startInternal(UserDatabaseRealm.java:264)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 17 more

Mar 20, 2017 3:22:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter hiddenHttpMethodFilter
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Mar 20, 2017 3:22:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Mar 20, 2017 3:22:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/rest] startup failed due to previous errors
Mar 20, 2017 3:22:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 20, 2017 3:22:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 20, 2017 3:22:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3063 ms
```

Here is a small form i wrote to see if i could get it working even with a hardcoded id sent to the delete method, although I can't access this as I only receive a 404 at the minute.

```
<form action="webapi/cds/1345" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE"/>
<p>ID : <input type="text" name="cdId" /></p>
<input type="submit" value="Delete"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you make sure `org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter` is inside your war-file (in sub-folder WEB-INF/lib)

Comment: Yea I have the 
 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping> 

is in my web.xml file which is inside my WEB-INF folder

Comment: No, I meant is the jar-file containing this class in your war-file? The last error you get is `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter`